# target same class different id

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems there is a mistake in targeting the child element, it seems not to work on hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.requested_user').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var currentIdMouse = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .requested_user').css("text-decoration", "underline");
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .requested_user').css("color", "blue");
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .popup_window').show();
  });
  $('.requested_user').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var currentIdMouse = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .requested_user').css("text-decoration", "none");
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .requested_user').css("color", "white");
    $('#' + currentIdMouse + ' .popup_window').hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.requested_user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.requested_user:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup_window {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="requested_user" id="item1">
  item1 content
  <div class="popup_window" id="item1">item1 popup content</div>
</div>

<div class="requested_user" id="item2">
  item2 content
  <div class="popup_window" id="item2">item2 popup content</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xht48eLg/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `live` is dead. What jq version are you using?

Comment: @A.Wolff I pasted the jquery file

Comment: @LW001 on mouseover I want display popup window, and mouseleave back to hidden for each id element

Comment: Your fiddle does not include the jquery library. Also the `.live` method has been removed since version 1.9

Comment: @MJohnson `$.fn.live()` has been removed from jq1.9. But regarding your HTML markup, you even don't need any js/jQuery. Just use CSS. BTW, IDs must be unique on document context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the id lookup at all.  The `this` is the requested_user in the handler, and the `popup_window` is a child of it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.requested_user').on('mouseenter', function() {
    this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    this.style.color = 'blue';
    $('.popup_window', this).show();
  });
  $('.requested_user').on('mouseleave', function() {
    this.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    this.style.color = 'white';
    $('.popup_window', this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.requested_user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.requested_user:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup_window {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="requested_user" id="item1">
  item1 content
  <div class="popup_window">item1 popup content</div>
</div>

<div class="requested_user" id="item2">
  item2 content
  <div class="popup_window">item2 popup content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I chose it as best answer. You can put this into your answer. https://jsfiddle.net/xht48eLg/5/

Answer (score 0):

So close, just change `.live` for `.on`, such that:

`$('.requested_user').live('mouseenter', function() {`
becomes `$('.requested_user').on('mouseenter', function() {`

and `$('.requested_user').live('mouseleave', function() {`
becomes `$('.requested_user').on('mouseleave', function() {`

Check out the updated version of your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MarcDBosse91/xht48eLg/1/

Also, as stated in the comments by @Peter Darmis:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live() [api.jquery.com/live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I guess OP wants some delegation

Comment: `on()` and `live()` have different signatures for delegation. You can't just switch the methods without also changing selectors around

Comment: It's because you're not including jQuery, try again

Comment: You could simply add also this to your answer. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Sweet, can you set this as answer :D

Comment: Not sure how the person above added anything that wasn't in my answer but okay... back to no commenting thanks, didn't know I should have revised every line in your code. :/

Comment: @MarcBosse it's okay both answers are working. best answer means it's the best, that doesn't mean others are wrong. Your answer is good too